# AWS S3 Data Protection Using Client-Side Encryption

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to use AWS S3 feature - [Protecting Data Using Client-Side Encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html)

According to AWS documentation the following AWS SDKs support client-side encryption:

```
AWS SDK for Java
AWS SDK for .NET
AWS SDK for Ruby
```

I have to use this functionality from Python. Is any way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client-side encryption means that you are encrypting the file prior to uploading it to S3. You can accomplish that using any programming language along with any encryption tool. For that matter, you could just use a tool like gpg and the AWS CLI to encrypt and upload files to S3. You manage the encryption keys on your side. The referenced SDKs just include a wrapper that simplify some of the client-side encryption operations.